# Slickgrid autoscrolling window on grid click

Tags: slickgrid

When enableCellNavigation is enabled, the initial click and double-click on my grid immediately scrolls the page down so that the clicked row is at the top of the screen. This is quite annoying since it is not expected. Is there some way to turn this off? If enableCellNavigation is disabled, rows cannot be selected so this is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `focusOnCurrentCell()`
In my case grid was scrolling to the end horizontally when clicked.
Commenting the `focusOnCurrentCell()` inside the function `setSelectedCell(newCell,editMode)` solved my problem.